# adding https to any URL before opening it via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, bookmarklet

I am building a javascript bookmarklet which can change some part of url and can open updated URL. Below is the code I have written.

```
var str   = "www.myweb.com/in/products/index.aspx";

var pattern2 = new RegExp('www.myweb.com','i');
var str1 = str.replace(pattern2, 'https://www-stg.myweb.com:60002'); 
window.location.href = str1;
```

This is resulting in http//www-stg.myweb.com:60002/in/products/index.aspx which in incorrect. I want to add `https://` before `www-stg.myweb.com`
If I `alert` it or `console.log()` it, it will show correct thing. But browser is adding `http` once submitted.

How to overcome this?

Comment: It should be `window.location.href = str1;`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Regent: sorry, i have updated it. Still the matter is - it is not recognizing colon in `https://www-stg.myweb.com:60002` and it is opening as `https//www-stg.myweb.com:60002/in/products/index.aspx`

Comment: Looks like it works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abt9srbm/).

Comment: @manoj, It is working man, Both in mozilla and chrome here, can you please tell me the brower name and version of browser you are using.

Comment: @Regent: yes it works in fiddle, try to add it as bookmark and click on it. It wont work

Comment: @SAM: Google chrome 37.0.2062.103 m

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an **anchor** element for such operations. No need for complicated expressions.

```
var str = '//www.myweb.com/in/products/index.aspx';

var a      = document.createElement('a');
a.href     = str;
a.protocol = 'https';
a.host     = 'www-stg.myweb.com:60002';

console.log('result', a.href);
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceo9ogm5/1)**</kbd>

<sup>Make sure `str` begins with `//` or `http://`, otherwise the current hostname will be used.</sup>

Comment: Making the browser do the work is the best way (you could also use `new URL`), but it looks like you can't assume a protocol will be given

Comment: here is the complete code which i am using for bookmarklet - `javascript:
var str   = document.URL;
 
 var pattern2 = new RegExp('www.myweb.com','i');
 var str1 = str.replace(pattern2, 'https://www-stg.myweb.com:60002');
 window.location.href = (str1); `

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus protocol is always https and I need to make it as a bookmarklet.